# 'Randomness' of inverses of $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose you are given the group $(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, where $p$ is prime. Let $A_p$ denote the sequence whose $j$th element is the inverse of $[j]$. For instance, if $p = 7$, the sequence $A_7$ is $(1,4,5,2,3,6)$. Suppose you truncate the sequence upto the $\alpha p$th term (where $\alpha$ is a very small constant compared to $1$). Then, as $p$ approaches $\infty$, is the set of all elements in this truncated sequence approximately uniform on $\{ 1,2,3,4, \ldots, p-1 \}$?

Note: This is NOT homework. I only want to gain some intuition.

Comment: But the point is that if you keep $\alpha$ fixed, then as $p$ approaches infinity, the sequence truncated to the $\alpha p$th term will also contain infinitely many terms.

Comment: Did you have any particular definition in mind for 'approximately uniform'? Presumably you'd like to be able to say something like 'the intersection with e.g. $(\beta p, \gamma p)$ contains approximately $p\cdot\alpha\cdot(\gamma-\beta)$ elements', for instance this number plus a quantity that's $o(p)$?

Comment: Yes, that would be an appropriate definition.

Comment: You've asked the same question twice, right? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330898/some-intuition-about-modular-multiplicative-inverses